# update view form model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was wrote this function in my model :

```
public function get_writers()
{
    $this->db->select('writer');
    $query = $this->db->get('news');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And I want to run a `foreach` loop on result of this array in my view file :

```
<label for="writer">Writer</label>
<select name="writer" id="writer">
    <?php foreach (??? as $each): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $each['id'] ?>"><?php echo $each['writer'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

But I don't know what should I write in the first parameter in `foreach` loop.Can anybody help me with this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the function get_writers() in controller like :-

```
$writers = $this->your_model->get_writers();
```

Then you need to  assign this $result variable data in view section like :-

```
 $this->view->load('view_page',array('writers'=>$writers));
```

After that you can use that variable data in form in view section.

```
<label for="writer">Writer</label>
<select name="writer" id="writer">
    <?php foreach ($writers as $each): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $each['id'] ?>"><?php echo $each['writer'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value on controller and pass to view like this:

**MODEL**

```
public function get_writers()
{
    $this->db->select('writer');
    $query = $this->db->get('news');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**CONTROLLER** (inside of your method)

```
$this->view->load('your_page_in_view_path', array('result' => $this->model->get_writers()));
```

**VIEW**

```
<label for="writer">Writer</label>
<select name="writer" id="writer">
    <?php foreach ($result as $each): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $each['id'] ?>"><?php echo $each['writer'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```